# (Swift) UICollectionViewCell Nested Subviews With Gesture Recognizers

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer, uicollectionviewcell

In `storyboard`, I've created a custom `UICollectionViewCell` embedded with two separate `UIViews`, which individually have embedded its own set of UI elements.

Based on a certain condition, I am showing/hiding the embedded `UIViews`.

The problem I cannot solve is triggering multiple touch events within the displayed `UIView`. For example, a touch event on click of a trash button and another for a click of the surrounding `UIView` itself.

Below is the relevant code snippet from my `UIViewController`:

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! ExampleCollectionViewCell

    cell.FirstUIView.isHidden = true
    cell.SecondUIView.isHidden = false

    let tap = UIGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onEdit))
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    cell.SecondUIView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    cell.SecondUIView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    cell.SecondUIViewTrashButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onDelete), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using UITapGestureRecognizer instead of UIGestureRecognizer.